# How to draw in the background colour in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

Imagine I want to do the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{block}{A braiding}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[braiding/.style={thick,preaction={draw,white,line width=2.3pt}}]
                \draw[braiding] (0,0) -- (1,1);
                \draw[braiding] (1,0) -- (0,1);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the `braiding` style, I actually want the `preaction` not in `white`, but in the background colour. Well of course I could dive into the beamer source code, find the colour and plug it in, but I want a general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{default}
%\usecolortheme{rose}
%\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usecolortheme{albatross}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{block}{A braiding}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[braiding/.style={thick,preaction={draw,bg,line width=2.3pt}}]
                \draw[braiding] (0,0) -- (1,1);
                \draw[braiding] (1,0) -- (0,1);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The colour is `bg`.

[image]

Comment: Spot on! I tried `background` and `background color` before. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @Turion Yes, in the `beamer` manual.

Comment: @HenriMenke, oh, then it's not TikZ-specific? How would I do it in TikZ without beamer?