# background colour in standalone

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, standalone

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(a) at (0.0, 0.0)[anchor=south west]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};
  \draw[blue, fill=bg] (0.15\paperwidth, 0.0\paperwidth) rectangle (0.3\paperwidth, 0.15\paperwidth);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the colour of the rectangle to exactly match the background colour in `standalone`. I checked [How to draw in the background colour in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269799/how-to-draw-in-the-background-colour-in-tikz) but it appears it is `beamer` specific.

Comment: there is no background color.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, then is `fill=white` the best answer ?

Comment: `fill=white` will fill with white color, if don't fix a `fill` color, the object will be transparent, letting you to see the background. By the way, your code doesn't compile, `bg` color is not defined.

Comment: you may try `\pagecolor{cyan}` for example